# Configurable not resetting after selecting either size/color

Tags: configurable-product, select

I have an issue regarding configurables and the best way I can explain it is through an example.

If I'm looking at a product with size and colors, I can first either pick size then colors, or colors then size.  Picking size first will gray out colors that are out of stock for that size. And vice versa, picking colors first will gray out the sizes not in stock for that color.

The problem arises in a situation where I pick size (medium) , then color (red), and realize I want to pick a different size now.  Naturally, I set the color option back to "choose an option" and attempt to change the size.  However, the size is grayed out for large, and only allows me to pick medium again.  Is there a way in the configurable.phtml file, or the js file to reset the choices when clicking on the "choose an option" selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

It's wrong to block selection for items that are greyed out. Magento is confusing selection with adding to cart. One thing has nothing to do with the other.

You should be able to select colors to view them for example - you just can't order them.

Comment: I solved this problem in a very hacky way. I made it so when you select "choose an option", it will refresh the page, thus refreshing the entire select drop down.  hacky, but it works pretty seemlessly.

Comment: I wanted to do this but I couldn't find anything on how to achieve it - Probably using incorrect terminology.